# CSS IE7 slow overlay

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, overlay

When i press a button an overlay appears. In Firefox the overlay is fast, nothing special. But in IE7 the overlay is very slow. I was wonder why?

Here is my CSS:

```
.DocOverlayShow
{
    background: url("/Graphics/overlay bg.png");
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    width:100%; 
    position:fixed; 
    padding:10px; 
}
.DocAddCommentBox
{
    color: #000;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 650px;
}
```

The overlay is activated when i click a button. Everything in IE works fine, but the overlay is soooo slow. Any ideas how come?

EDIT:
When i use Opacity and filter, everything on this div is also transparant. This i don't want. On the overlay div i have another div (DocAddCommentBox). This div may not have transparancy. How can i solve this?

EDIT: Solution:

```
.DocOverlayShow
{
    background-color: #0057C3;
    Opacity:0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /*IE*/
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    width:100%; 
    height: 100px;
    position:fixed; 
    padding:10px; 
    z-index: 1000;
}
.DocAddCommentBox
{
    background-color: #DBDBDB;
    color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    width: 450px;
    z-index:2000;
}
```

And in html i've used:

```
<div class="DocOverlayShow"></div>
<div class="DocAddCommentBox">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your overlay.png have an alpha channel/transparency? If so, try it without the transparency. From memory, IE is horribly slow at rendering such things.

What I would do is use CSS for transparency.

Set opacity like so:

```
Opacity:0.5;
```

Unfortunately it's not supported in IE, so we also have to use a custom IE attribute:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
```

Comment: The pg is about 3x3 px and has a transparacy yes. How do i have to create a transparancy png that is also working fine with IE7?

Comment: You cant. What I would do is use CSS for transparency. Set opacity like so: 'Opacity:0.5;' Unfortunately it's not supported in IE, so we also have to use a custom IE attribute-  'filter: alpha(opacity=50);'

Comment: Thnx i will try it. Does every site do it like that? Or do they use a .gif or something?

Comment: They use a div with the background-color set to black or similar, that means they don't use a picture.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need the opacity syntax, all you need to do is to make your transparent images bigger than 1px or 2px, minimum 20px will work. Mainly, images with background-repeat and specially the ones that have many repeats to fill the empty space they make your IE7 much slower than the others.

Answer (score 0):

here' s the CSS of overlay that I used in my project:

```
#siteol {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:10000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

<!--[if IE]>
/* style for IE */
<style type="text/css">
#siteol  {
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

just get rid of the PNG.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and the following solution worked perfectly without playing with the additional opacity attribute. It still requires IE to use filter but feels cleaner to me.

```
background-color: rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.6);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0, StartColorStr='#7ff4f4f4', EndColorStr='#7ff4f4f4');
```

A great explanation for the IE filter gradient trick and benefits of not using opacity attribute on backgrounds can be found below

http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/